# How to select specific dates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, date, dml

My table:

```
create table example
(
        code           varchar(7),
        date           date,
CONSTRAINT pk_date PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

Dates:

```
insert into example(code, date) 
values('001','2016/05/12');
insert into example(code, date) 
values('002','2016/04/11');
insert into example(code, date) 
values('003','2017/02/03');
```

My problem: how to select the previous dates to six month from today ?

In MySQL I can use PERIOD_DIFF,but, in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `INTERVAL` instruction :

```
SELECT date
FROM example
WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '6 months'
AND date > CURRENT_DATE;
```

You will get the dates from today to six months.